# Orbeon, overriding model.xml and form.xhtml

Tags: compilation, war, orbeon

Is there posibility to override files form.xhtml and model.xml (and template.xml) without compiling Orbeon sources ? I want to add field to form metedata, and I don't know, is it sufficient to add properly files to resource/orbeon/builder/form in my exploded .war file.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

(That must have been the shortest answer I got a chance to post here!)

To expand on this a little bit, if you want to override Form Builder's `form.xhtml`, you can place your version in `WEB-INF/resources/forms/orbeon/builder/form/form.xhtml`. And of course, if there is any way to avoid this, you might want to consider it, as custom changes make it harder to upgrade, and can become quite a nuisance.